# Spring Boot cron expression Problem - Disable run at the start up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I have a Spring boot application with a scheduled job. All I want is simply launch my job every day at 12 PM, but I don't want the job starts at the startup of the Spring boot application.

My cron expression is `0 0 12 1/1 * ? *`

Can someone help me?

Comment: corn expression will not start like that

Comment: Have you read this tutorial [Scheduling Tasks](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) on Spring official website?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * *")
//@Scheduled(fixedRate = 4000)
public void processMyTask() {
   ...
}
```

This cron expression **"0 0 12 * * *"** should work. The fixedRate value I use when I am doing development and want to execute for testing purposes, so please make sure your method is properly annotated.